# Multiple serializers in a single ListAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a APIView where I list the data and the same displayed data can be exported to XLS file or PDF file apart from the data which uses the same serializer fields to be displayed on the file. Now I am adding a couple of new fields which needs to be on file but not displayed on website, I want to create a new serializer with all the fields along with couple of new fields for exporting them to the file ExportSerializer.

```py
class MyDataListAPIView(ListExportMixin, ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    ordering = '-created'
    ordering_param = 'ordering'
  
    export_fields = (
        'number',
        'issue_date_formatted',
        'due_date_formatted',
        'hearing_date',
        'status',
        'total_amount_formatted',
        'amount_received_formatted',
        'balance_formatted',
        'unapplied_amount_sum_display',
        'firm',
        'last_past_due_sent_on_formatted',
        'fee_amount_formatted',
        'payments_formatted',
    )
    column_header = {
        'titles': [
            
        ],
        'header_title': 'Statement of Services Rendered'
    }
```

I want Myserializer to be used to list the data but I want the other serializer called SecondSerializer just for exporting how can I achieve that when I am exporting the data to file I need to use SecondSerializer but when I want to just list I need Myserializer mentioned in the view.

Comment: You can achieve that using https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself method.

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan but how can my conditions be i have nothing apart from export fields mentioned in the view

Comment: You have to look at the `ListExportMixin`'s code. The condition might be based on the request method or some query parameter. It depends on the implementation of `ListExportMixin`.